# speak text using html5

Tags: javascript, html, text, speech

I've been looking on the web for a while and can't seem to find api for you to make html5 speak predefined text. I have a list of numbers in an array and I want html5 to speak the numbers in 1 second intervals. Anyone know how to make html5/ javascript talk numbers?

Comment: There are still some things HTML5 can't do natively ,-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Microsoft SAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make an application converting text to speech but it is very hard to find some good tutorials about it, almost only on-line documentation.